# print second lowest number from a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm new to python and I have been forcing myself into logic first to resolve problems.

I have been trying to figure out the best way to compare float numbers within the list to get the lowest second numbers from the list.

`numbers = [40, 40, 10, 10, 21, 21, 100,100, 400,400, 15, 15]`

from the above list, I want to get: 15 and 15 since they are both the lowest numbers. **I don't care if they duplicates, so no need to remove the duplicates with set()**

My approach:

I thought about a for loop and compare it but I got stuck. Maybe enumerate can help me to compare the numbers?

Additionally, how do you recommend improving logic to resolve problems?I have been focusing on hackerrank exercises so far.

thank you!

Comment: @Tibebes.M Won't work, as there is two 10 in the list. And sorted will return onlyone value, not both

Comment: @Tibebes.M I read it : " I want to get: 15 and 15 since they are both the lowest numbers."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that with

```py
second_smallest = sorted(set(numbers))[1]
[i for i in numbers if i == second_smallest]
```

Explaining:

- `set(numbers)` will remove duplicates
- `sorted` will order the list asc
- Then we just loop over them and filter only the second smallest

HackerRank is a good place for you to improve, but you should also get involved in other projects that have wider tests and challenges. Stack Overflow is a good place for that :)

Comment: It would be better to do something like: `num = sorted(set(numbers))[1] ; [num] * numbers.count(num)`

Comment: @Tomerikoo what do you think about the edit that I made? I think loops are easier to understand in that matter

Comment: Nice. That's readable and more efficient than before :)

Comment: thank you Gustavo, it looks like your solution helped me to move forward!

Answer (score 2):

Since you're a beginner and you probably want to learn how to think about these problems in addition to the inbuilt way to do this, here's a method that doesn't use a prewritten function to sort the list. We're going to loop over the list and keep track of the smallest and second-smallest items.

```
smallestnum = [numbers[0]] # This will keep track of all smallest numbers we've found
secsmallest = [numbers[0]] # This will hold all second-smallest numbers we find
for element in numbers:
    if element < smallestnum[0]:
        # This is the new minimum
        # So the old minimum is now the second-smallest
        secsmallest = smallestnum
        smallestnum = [element]
    elif element == smallestnum[0]:
        # Add this number to our list of smallests
        smallestnum.append(element)
    elif element < secsmallest[0]:
        # This is the new second-smallest
        secsmallest = [element]
    elif element == secsmallest[0]:
        # Add this to our list of 2nd smallest
        secsmallest.append(element)
    # else do nothing
```

Answer (score 0):

```
numbers = [40, 40, 10, 10, 21, 21, 100,100, 400,400, 15, 15]
def second_lowest_number():
        numbers.sort()
        z = numbers[0]
for i in numbers:
        if i > z:
            print(i)
            break
second_lowest_number()
```

This will give answer regardless of duplicates

Comment: While code-only answers might answer the question, you could significantly improve the quality of your answer by providing context for your code, 
a reason for why this code works, and some references to documentation for further reading.
_"Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better."_
Please take the [tour] and read [answer]. Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Answer (score 0):

A working and efficient solution:

```
>>> s = set(numbers)
>>> s.remove(min(s))
>>> x = min(s)
>>> [x] * numbers.count(x)
[15, 15]
```

Or with O(1) space:

```
>>> x = min(numbers)
>>> y = min(y for y in numbers if y != x)
>>> [y] * numbers.count(y)
[15, 15]
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do the following:

```
sorted(set(numbers))[1]
```

- `set(numbers)` creates a set from the list: each value is kept only one
- `sorted(set(numbers))` sorts the values from smallest to tallest
- `sorted(set(numbers))[1]` retrieves the second lowest

Comment: They _don't_ want to remove duplicates